# Read Object from non-rewinding tape

Tags: java, io

I'm writing several Serializable Java Objects to tape.

The code works without problem when reading the written Objects using a rewinding device (/dev/st0), but it never succeeds when reading those same Objects using a non-rewinding device (/dev/nst0).

The failure always occurs in the first readObject() call, returning a StreamCorruptedException.

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream (
        new FileInputStream( device ), 2*1024*1024 );
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( bis );
Object oisObject = ois.readObject();
```

The exception:error message and relevant stack trace are:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 9AF03B07
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
```

Am hopeful that someone might be able to help me understand why this is occurring only with the non-rewinding device, and perhaps also suggest a possible remedy to the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you somehow verify that reading works in general from this device, i.e. by just writing a ton of bytes to the device with a normal output stream and reading it in again with an input stream?

Comment: Yes, validating the infrastructure is a must.  In this case, the tape drive and device files function properly using Linux commands and Java Input/Output Streams.  The problem currently seems isolated to readObject(), and only via a non-rewinding device.

Comment: Error message and stack trace are both missing from this question.

Comment: Yes, why didn't I add those in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

Note that the exception is thrown from `new ObjectInputStream()`, and the hex number tells you what the first four bytes of that stream were. This means that whatever is in that device, it doesn't start with an `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction on where the Exception is being thrown, as well as the information on the additional bytes in the error message.  After creating additional and more complex test cases, I'm still unable to reproduce the error outside of the application.  Since this code has and continues to function properly with "st0" for "years" [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1144817) (thanks for the earlier help, btw), I come back to what could possibly be different with "nst0"?  Something with the file pointer?  I can write with either st0/nst0, but can only read back with st0.

Comment: Found in my code an earlier "peek" at the Objects, thus explaining why only the non-rewinding device was throwing the exception.  Oh, the shame... :)